# Append an array to another array

Tags: python, numpy

##### I have a problem with `np.append(ar,values, axis=None)`

*Take a look at following codes:*

```py
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([])
array2 = np.array([1,2])
array3 = np.array([3,4])
array4 = np.array([5,6])

array1 = np.append(array1, array2)
array1 = np.append(array1, array3)
array1 = np.append(array1, array4)

print(array1) # [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6.]
```

So this is not what i want i want add exactly the array to the array1
and the array1 should be

```
[[1. 2.]
 [3. 4.]
 [5. 6.]]
```

How can i do that?

Comment: you just want `np.stack([array2, array3, array4])`

Comment: don't use `np.append` - unless you want to add just one number to a 1d array.

Comment: @amirhosseinzibaei is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `stack` the arrays.

```
array1 = np.stack([array2, array3, array4])
```

should do it.

Comment: `ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape`

Comment: Corrected the answer, stack takes a list (or array like) of other arrays that you want to stack vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([])
array2 = np.array([1,2])
array3 = np.array([3,4])
array4 = np.array([5,6])
a = np.append(array1, array2)
b = np.append(array1, array3)
c = np.append(array1, array4)
print(np.vstack((a, b, c)))
```

output:

```
[[1. 2.]
 [3. 4.]
 [5. 6.]]
```